# Android service returns both START_STICKY and START_NOT_STICKY

Tags: android, service, background

I am trying to understand how Android handles Background services, and so far i got that services where the onStartCommand callback returns START_STICKY get kept alive by the OS, unless it has a reason to not auto-restart them due to battery optimizations.

What if a service, that first returned START_STICKY returns START_NOT_STICKY the second time its onStartCommand is called?

Does the whole service state change to NOT_STICKY?

Answer (score -1):

That's kind of really outdated info.  These days background services are killed after 2 minutes.  It doesn't matter what they return.  They will not be restarted after that.  Possibly they still would if killed before then, but I kind of doubt it.

Comment: I disagree. Services can survive fairly long and Sticky ones have a chance of being restarted. If battery optimization is enabled for an app they could be left dead, though. I think non-battety-optimized services will be reliably restarted, although they have some sort of backoff delay.

Comment: @DanielD. Not on modern Android.  2 minutes is the ABSOLUTE LIMIT for a background service.  You need to update your knowledge.  THis is a documented limit of the OS  There is no such thing as a "non battery optimized service".  There are foreground services, but those have a separate set of limitations.

Comment: Just for further info  https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background "While an app is in the foreground, it can create and run both foreground and background services freely. When an app goes into the background, it has a window of several minutes in which it is still allowed to create and use services. At the end of that window, the app is considered to be idle. At this time, the system stops the app's background services, just as if the app had called the services' Service.stopSelf() methods."  Several has ended up being 2.

Comment: Fair, I can't speak for newer android versions. With 11, my services stayed online for quite a while, and after un-battery-optimizing my app my service does not seem to get left to die. My service reliably gets restarted.

Comment: In any case, even if we only look at the two minutes of background lifetime of a service, START_STICKY still does it's job. So, my question still stands...